# Viewing shared segments created by shmget

Tags: linux, proc, shared-memory

I'm trying to "visualize" shared memory between two processes. I've created a little server-client example where the client writes some data to a shared memory location and the server reads from it. I'm using the usual code for this:

```
(shmid = shmget(key, SHMSZ, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0
```

Now, I need to know that while the server and client are running, how do I actually see in some memory map or something that both have the same memory shared between them i.e. is there something in `/proc/<pid>/` file that I can read and interpret?

I tried reading from `smaps` but that doesn't really look like what I need.

Comment: What kind of information do you want? `ipcs` gives some stuff for starters, why smaps doesn't suit your uses?

Comment: Well, I'd actually like to get the physical frame number so that I can actually see that some page is shared between the two processes.